# How do you set the width of the browser using Google Chrome

Tags: testing, google-chrome

In IE you can set the browser width to be 1024x768, for example, to test your site. How can you do this in Chrome? I can't find an equivalent setting anywhere? I'm using 'Tools -> Developer tools'.

I can't do the fallback trick of running

```
javascript:window.resizeTo(1024,768)
```

in the location bar, because Chrome tries to search for it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must *type* (not copy-paste) the entire Javascript (including "javascript:") into the address bar to execute Javascript - Chrome will strip the "javascript:" protocol specification and treat your Javascript as a search if your last action in the address bar is copy-pasting.

A more convenient way to execute arbitrary Javascript in Chrome would be to open the Javascript Console (Ctrl+Shift+J), however, the `resizeTo()` function [is not supported for tabs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091) so you'll need to enter something creative in the console to make this work:

```
var myTestWindow = window.open(window.location); myTestWindow.resizeTo(1024,768);
```

(subsequent changes to the pop-up window's size can be made by calling `myTestWindow.resizeTo(x,y)`)

Comment: +1 That JS console way works, thanks. It's a bit inconvenient, but in the absense of anything better it's fine

Comment: @Ralph I'd advise against doing this, it incredibly annoying for users to have their browser resized.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - *"...to test your site..."*

Comment: Oh, my bad. To be honest it's probably better to resize by hand. I'd wager that no web browser window is ever sized at 1024x768, with task bars and toolbars and such.